# A question on numerical range

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{array}} \right)$.

What is numerical range of $A$?

Comment: What is "numerical range" compared to the normal range?

Comment: Have you heard of something called the *column space* of a matrix?

Comment: @Arthur: Are you giving a hint or asking for the definition? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range)

Comment: @Roland no, I was actually asking. It was not a phrase I had heard before, and some times that means that it's just a phrase the problem author came up with on the spot.

Comment: I think this numerical range is the dimension of the subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ determined by the function $AX=Y$ of $\mathbb R^4$ in itself. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Ataulfo: In functional analysis, the numerical range denotes the set of all complex values of the form $(Ax,x)$, where $x$ run through all vectors with norm one and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the scalar product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numerical range of 
$$
A(\{1,4\}) =  \pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}
$$
is $[-1,1] \subset \Bbb R$.  This is easy to find as the matrix is Hermitian.

The numerical range of 
$$
A(\{2,3\}) = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
is $\{z \in \Bbb C : |z| < 1\}$, as you may verify from direct computation.

The numerical range of $A$ is the convex hull of these two sets, which is simply $\{z \in \Bbb C : |z| < 1\}$.

---

Let
$$
P = \pmatrix{
1\\
&&&1\\
&&1\\
&1\\
}
$$
Note that $P$ is a permutation matrix (and is thus unitary), so $A$ and $P^*AP$ have the same numerical range.

Note that $PAP^*$ is block diagonal with
$$
PAP^* = \pmatrix{
0&1\\
1&0\\
&&0&1\\
&&0&0
}
$$
the conclusion follows.

Comment: Why can you split the problem into the convex hull of the two smaller matrices? Is it because $AW_{1,4} \perp W_{2,3}$ and  $AW_{2,3} \perp W_{1,4}$, where $W_{i,j}=\mbox{span} \{e_i,e_j\}$?

Comment: It's because $W_{1,4}$ and $W_{2,3}$ are both orthogonal to each other and invariant subspaces of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Thanks, Which theorem say that If ${W_{1,4}},{W_{2,3}}$ are both orthogonal to each other and invariant subspaces of $A$ then numerical range of $A$ is  the convex hull of these two sets?Please guide me.

Comment: @H.S you should have a theorem about block diagonal matrices. This is precisely that theorem, up to an appropriate unitary similarity. That is, another way to interpret my answer is to say that $A$ is unitarily similar to a block diagonal matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom - Thank you ,Please explain easier.

Comment: @H.S see my edit